# Can I use haproxy with only one NIC?

Tags: linux, haproxy

I understand haproxy should have one NIC for the incoming traffic and another one facing the web servers. But since all my servers are on a public networks exposed to internet, could I sue a simple dedicated server with only one NIC? The main question is: haproxy's performance will be affected from this?

Answer (score 1):

haproxy's performance will only be affected if you clog the NIC; otherwise it'll work just fine.

Comment: what clog the NIC means?

Comment: Utilise all the available bandwidth.

Comment: You can also "clog the NIC" with large numbers of small packets, and still have bandiwdth available. This could manifest itself as a large number of interrupts on the device, and might be common in an application where there are many small requests and replies (such as  a RESTful web servies).